# How can I pull a data from any a web site through webrequest in c#?

Tags: c#

How can I pull a data from any a web site through webrequest in c#? e.g price of the product in www.xxx.com

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest that you take a look at [Html Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/). It provides you with a lot of good functionality for parsing web pages.

Answer (score 2):

For ANY website - good luck. That is near impossible.

Some websites, however provide an api for you to call and then parse the response. Usually this involves calling their web services/methods and passing in parameters either through a query string. Then hopefully the response is clean enough for you to easily manage.

If they have one, they will advertise it usually. Then you can add the web service as a service reference and use that to make your calls.